# Anonymous User gets cookie

Tags: sessions, cookies

I recently saw that when I open of my sites as a anonymous user, a session cookie is set. I checked the database sessions table, and there is a line for uid 0 as well.
How can I prevent drupal from setting this cookie?

Greetings SG

This is what the cookie looks like in the session table:

[image]

Sry that the image is so tiny ...

Comment: And why would you want that, exactly?

Comment: I want to work with Nginx and this is checking if a session cookie is set or not.

Comment: Drupal 7 already only sets session cookie for anonymous if there is something session-dependent, like form, or module that needs sessions. "Simply" remove everything that requires sessions for anonymous and you are set. For Drupal 6, see https://www.drupal.org/project/no_anon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments above, the problem where provided by the "Pagestyle" module. The 7.x-1.0 is pretty old for now and its creating this cookie for any anonymous user.

You can fix the problem by updating the module to the newest dev release. After this you've to configure the module here: admin/config/user-interface/pagestyle

And set "Scripting languages" to "PHP + JavaScript + Optimized for performance"

Answer (score 2):

Drupal7 unlike drupal6 does not use sessions for anon users. This is an improvement for performance reasons. If you see that there are sessions created it means that there is a contrib module that creates them, so it may be a bad idea disabling them. You can inspect the contents of the session to get an idea which module is using it.

If this is d6 site, you may check the pressflow distribution.

Comment: Thx for your respons. I first thought the cookie gots added by my search form, but i was wrong with it ... For now it looks like it sometimes appears, and sometimes it disappears :/
I updated my post with my session table.

Comment: It seems that you are using the pagestyle module ?

Comment: I saw it myself in the moment I did the screenshot ... :O
After updating the module to the latest dev, the cookie is gone, I'll create a answer for this question.